# gradle publishing not working - No such Algorithm

Tags: ssl, gradle, publishing

I have a nexus repository that I want to publish my gradles versions catalog to.  Here's the gradle build script:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0")
    }

}
plugins {
    id ("version-catalog")
    id ("maven-publish")
}
catalog {
    versionCatalog {
        from(files("gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("VersionCatalog") {
            groupId = "com.phinneyridge"
            artifactId = "com.phinneyridge.version.catalog"
            version = "1.0.0"
            from(components["versionCatalog"])
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "PhinneyRidgeRepository"
                url = uri(System.getenv()["PhinneyRidgeReleaseRepoUrl"].toString())
                credentials {
                    username = System.getenv().get("PhinneyRidgeRepoUser").toString()
                    password = System.getenv().get("PhinneyRidgeRepoUserPW").toString()
                }
                println(url)
                println(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output I get when I try to publish:

> gradlew publish
> Type-safe dependency accessors is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :
> https://ridgetop/nexus/repository/maven-releases/
> publisher:mavenpublisher

> Task :publishVersionCatalogPublicationToPhinneyRidgeRepositoryRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':publishVersionCatalogPublicationToPhinneyRidgeRepositoryRepository'.

> Failed to publish publication 'VersionCatalog' to repository 'PhinneyRidgeRepository'
> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.
> SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

If I changed the maven repository to mavenLocal(), the script actually publishes the version catalog to the local maven repository just fine.

What's also interesting, is that I have a custom gradle plugin in a different build script and it fairly well the same looking code pattern, and it successfully publishes the custom gradle plugin to same repository.  Here's the code for that working script:

```
plugins {
    id ("java-gradle-plugin")

    "java-library"
    id ("maven-publish")
    id("com.gradle.plugin-publish") version "0.20.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.6.20"
    id("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl") version "2.1.7"
}
gradlePlugin {
    group = "com.phinneyridge"
    plugins {
        create("PhinneyRidgePlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.project"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeProjectPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeAndroidAppPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.android.application"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeAndroidAppPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeAndroidLibPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.android.library"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeAndroidLibPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeAndroidKotlinAppPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.android.kotlin.application"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeAndroidKotlinAppPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeAndroidKotlinLibPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.android.kotlin.library"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeAndroidKotlinLibPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeJavaAppPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.java.application"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeJavaAppPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeJavaLibPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.java.library"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeJavaLibPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeJavaKotlinAppPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.java.kotlin.application"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeJavaKotlinAppPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeJavaKotlinLibPlugin") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.java.kotlin.library"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.gradle.PhinneyRidgeJavaKotlinLibPlugin"
        }
        create("PhinneyRidgeDSAnnotations") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.dsannotations"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.osgi.DSAnnotations"
        }
        create("Aar2Jar") {
            id = "com.phinneyridge.aar2jar"
            implementationClass = "com.phinneyridge.android.Aar2Jar"
        }
    }
}
group = "com.phinneyridge"
version = "1.0.0"
publishing {
    repositories {
       maven {
           url = uri(System.getenv().get("PhinneyRidgeReleaseRepoUrl").toString())
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv().get("PhinneyRidgeRepoUser").toString()
                password = System.getenv().get("PhinneyRidgeRepoUserPW").toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
    gradleApi();
    implementation ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20")
}
```

There's some differences, but the maven repository is constructed exactly the same. So the question is why am I getting the NoSuchAlgorithm error when I try to publish the version catalog?

If I try publishing with stacktrace I see the following:

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.securit
y.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientConfigurer.jdkSupportsTLSProtocol(HttpClientConfigurer.java:115)
```

And here's what jdkSupportTLSProtocol looks like:

```
    private static boolean jdkSupportsTLSProtocol(@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue") final String protocol) {
    try {
        for (String supportedProtocol : SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()) {
            if (protocol.equals(supportedProtocol)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(e);
    }
}
```

It's the SSLContext.getDefault() that throws the NoSuchAlgorithException.  I'm just currently at a lost understand what I need to change to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to the problem.

I added a line of code to the maven repository declaration:

```
    maven {
            javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.setDefault(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("default"))
            name = "PhinneyRidgeRepository"
            url = uri(System.getenv()["PhinneyRidgeReleaseRepoUrl"].toString())
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv().get("PhinneyRidgeRepoUser").toString()
                password = System.getenv().get("PhinneyRidgeRepoUserPW").toString()
            }
            println(url)
            println(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
        }
    }
```

That solved the problem, but I don't have an explanation why I had to set the SSLContext in one situation and not the other.  According to the gradle documentation SSLContext.getDefault() is supposeto automagically call SSLContext.getInstance("Default") when the SSLContext is not initialized.  (By the way the instance name seems to be case insensitive, so "default" or "Default" both worked.) My speculation is that this is a gradle bug, probably because the publication in one case is from component. That's the only obvious difference that I see that sets the two contrasting situations apart.  By the way SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2") would not work; I had to use "default"